github action python unittest traverse all subdirectories
I'm making a codeleet project where the structure is
/codeleet
  /python
     /ex1
       -solution.py
       -test.py
     /ex2
       -solution.py
       -test.py

I use basic unittest to test run my tests. And I want to practice github actions to test all the code. But with python -m unittest discover I doesn't traverse the file structure to look for test files. python -m unittest discover -s 'python' -p 'test.py' also doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas?

Try adding a __init__.py file to your directories and provide it the top-level directory explicitly. Consider using pytest (which is a compatible runner even if your tests are using unittest).

thanks a lot, now they are indeed picked up, will definitely look into pytest
